# HTML JQuery: Pass selected value onclick to elements name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I currently have a dropdown menu so the user can select an option to refine their search by like so:

```
<button name = "toggle" tabindex="-3" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button">
<span class="caret"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
</button>

<ul class="dropdown-menu" >
<li><a href="#" name="restuatant"><span class="t">restaurant</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#" name="active"> <span class="t">beauty salon</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#" name="bars"> <span class="t">bars</span></a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#" name="other"> <span class="t">other</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

What I am wanting to do is when an option is selected from the drop down menu to update an elements name so I can then access whatever was selected on the form afters its been submitted. At the minute ive got this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('ul.dropdown-menu li').click(function()
     {
       var field = document.createElement("input");
       field.name=$(this).find("span.t").text();
     }
     });
     });
```

How would I go about doing what i specified because I am a little unsure

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I mean how do I update the elements name from with my function dynamically, each time its clicked

Comment: Your current code does this!

Comment: that creates a new element each time doesn't it? can u suggest an easy way to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood the question correctly you want to create an `input` element  and update it's `name` property on the click event. If this is the case you can code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     // create an input and append to #somewhere
     var $field = $('<input>').appendTo('#somewhere');
     $('ul.dropdown-menu li').click(function() {
         $field.prop('name', $(this).find("span.t").text());
     });
});
```

If the element should be generated on the first click:

```
var $field;
$('ul.dropdown-menu li').click(function() {
     var name = $(this).find("span.t").text().trim();
     if ( !$field ) {
        $field = $('<input>', {
           'type': 'text'
        }).appendTo('#somewhere');
     }
     $field.prop('name', name);
});
```

Comment: with regards to the #somewhere can it be a class

Comment: @Nebbyyy [It can be any valid selector.](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/#appendTo-target)